# MongoDB Geospatial query within an array returns always the full doc

Tags: mongodb, spatial-query

Have a collection in MongoDB that looks like this :

```
{
"_id" : "7613035010550",
"purchases" : [ 
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2017-04-15T14:15:00.000Z"),
        "coords" : {
            "lon" : 43.729604,
            "lat" : 1.416017
        },
        "metar" : {},
        "quantity" : 1,
        "price" : 2.31
    }, 
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2017-05-02T16:23:00.000Z"),
        "coords" : {
            "lon" : 43.722862,
            "lat" : 1.415837
        },
        "metar" : {},
        "quantity" : 6,
        "price" : 12
    }, 
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2017-05-02T18:32:00.000Z"),
        "coords" : {
            "lon" : 46.307353,
            "lat" : 3.28937
        },
        "metar" : {},
        "quantity" : 2,
        "price" : 5
    }
],
"rates" : [ 
    {
        "value" : 5
    }, 
    {
        "value" : 4
    }, 
    {
        "value" : 5
    }, 
    {
        "value" : 2
    }
]
}
```

And would like make a query that is abble to return only purchases done within a define radius (i.e 5 km) around a point and only for an id... But i don't know how to handle this kind of query.

Try this query :

```
db.getCollection('stats').find({"purchases.coords":{$geoWithin:{$centerSphere: [[43.688935, 1.401541], 25 / 6378.1]}}})
```

But returns the whole document... I would like to be abble to return something like an array of purchases made around the defined radius, i.e only those two in my exemple :

```
        {
        "date" : ISODate("2017-04-15T14:15:00.000Z"),
        "coords" : {
            "lon" : 43.729604,
            "lat" : 1.416017
        },
        "metar" : {},
        "quantity" : 1,
        "price" : 2.31
    }, 
    {
        "date" : ISODate("2017-05-02T16:23:00.000Z"),
        "coords" : {
            "lon" : 43.722862,
            "lat" : 1.415837
        },
        "metar" : {},
        "quantity" : 6,
        "price" : 12
    }
```

How can i achieve this kind of query... or... how to define my collection to be abble to make this kind of query ?

Thx,

JL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Your purpose I'd recommend to use aggregation with stages [project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and [unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/).

Can't check it right now but it should looks like this:

```
db.getCollection('stats').aggregate([
    {'$match': {
        "purchases.coords": {$geoWithin:{$centerSphere: [[43.688935, 1.401541], 25 / 6378.1]}}
    }},
    {'$project': {
        "_id": 0, // 0 - if you don't need document id
        "purchases": 1,
    }},
    {'$unwind': "$purchases"},
    {'$match': {
        "purchases.coords": {$geoWithin:{$centerSphere: [[43.688935, 1.401541], 25 / 6378.1]}}
    }},
])
```

I've used 2 identical matches to:

1. Match all documents matched specified conditions.
2. Match all unwinded 'purchase' matched specified conditions.

You can use this aggregation without first match but it may be a bit slower.

You can see how it works If you comment all the stages and then uncomment one by one.

Comment: Thx a lot...
I'm a total rookie with MongoDB and this solution is really efficient.
Next have to create this query with my PHP backend... lol